# C++ constexpr in place aligned storage construction

Tags: c++, c++14, variant

I'm trying to make an aligned variant type that uses std::aligned_storage to hold the data. Is there a way to construct an object in place in a constexpr way? I read you can't do constexpr placement new.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


struct foo
{
    foo(std::string a, float b)
    : bar1(a), bar2(b)
    {}

    std::string bar1;
    float bar2;
};


struct aligned_foo
{
    template<typename... Args>
    aligned_foo(Args&&... args) 
    {
        //How to constexpr construct foo?
        data_ptr = ::new((void*)::std::addressof(storage)) foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    std::aligned_storage<sizeof(foo)> storage;
    foo* data_ptr;
};


int main()
{
    aligned_foo("Hello", 0.5);
}
```

Comment: `std::string` doesn't have a `constexpr` constructor, so unlikely.

Comment: **Short answer:** No. **Long answer:** One of the possible reasons: The lifetime of an object of a class type begins when its constructor has completed. For `constexpr` contexts, the only sane way to manage such lifetimes is with objects of *automatic storage duration* or *static storage duration* - because the compiler can reason about these lifetimes easily. Maybe when our compilers get as capable as Rust, we can do better in this regard

Answer (score 1):

No. One of the long list of [expressions](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2) that can't appear in a constant expression is a [*new-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2.19).

The only way to implement a variant and have it be `constexpr`-friendly is through the use of a union. Although, even with a union, you still wouldn't be able to have a `constexpr`-friendly variant that can contain a `foo` since it's not a literal type (by way of it having a non-trivial destructor, by way of `std::string` having a non-trivial destructor).